# Ionic 5, login con facebook, solo funciona con mi mail de facebook

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Desarrollo app Ionic con login facebook

```
(Ionic CLI: 6.10.0 - Ionic Framework: @ionic/angular 5.6.11 
Cordova CLI: 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1) - Cordova Platforms: android 8.1.0)
```

(está en modo producción en developers facebook), y sucede lo siguiente:

Cuando la pruebo en mi móvil (Samsung A50, Android 11), con mi mail de facebook, funciona perfecto.

Cuando instalo apk en otro móvil (también Samsung A50, Android 11) y otro usuario/mail de facebook, **si borro chaché y datos** de la aplicación facebook en el móvil, la app Ionic hace login y da error buscando datos en getUserDetail. **Si no borro caché y datos** de la aplicación facebook en el móvil, da error en el login directamente *(error: 4201 User cancelled dialog)*.

Adjunto código (variables ya definidas antes), les agradeceré la ayuda que me puedan brindar, muchísimas gracias

```
...
import { Facebook, FacebookLoginResponse } from '@ionic-native/facebook/ngx';
...


constructor(
    ...
    private fb: Facebook,
    ...
) {}

fbLogin() {
    this.fb.login(['public_profile', 'email'])
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status === 'connected') {
          this.isLoggedIn = true;
          this.getUserDetail(res.authResponse.userID);
        } else {
          this.isLoggedIn = false;
        }
      })
      .catch(e => console.log('Error logging into Facebook', e));
  }
  getUserDetail(userid: any) {
    this.fb.api('/' + userid + '/?fields=id,email', ['public_profile'])
      .then(res => {
        this.users = res;
        this.global.email = this.users.email;
        this.router.navigate(["/menu", this.users.email]);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        alert("Error getUserDetail");
      });
  }
```